# WebSocket с серверной частью на php

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток, пытаюсь разобраться с вебсокетами, а именно с серверной его частью на php. С клиентской все просто:

```
<script>
    ws = new WebSocket("ws://site.com/demo");
    ws.onopen = function() { alert("Connection opened...") };
    ws.onclose = function() { alert("Connection closed...") };
    ws.onmessage = function(evt) { $("#msg").append("<p>"+evt.data+"</p>"); }; 
</script>
```

А вот с серверной... Перечитал кучу постов на хабре, тут, да и не только. Но никак не могу понять, для чего нужен phpDeamon или Ratchet, и в каких случаях они нужны? И в тени для меня осталось как их устанавливать на реальный хостинг, везде разговор ведется о установке на локальные серверы типа denwer или openserver. Просветите пожалайста

Comment: Нужен процесс который не умерает (демон). Библиотека которая позвоиляет писать WebSocket демонов Ratchetт.е. Пишем скрипт который слушает на любом порту. Потом запускаем его ` php script_name.php`, собственно все. Потом обертки что бы не падало.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Обычное построение веба основано на архитектуре "клиент-сервер". Т.е. есть клиентские машины, а есть сервера, которые ожидают запросы от клиентов, обрабатывают эти запросы и отправляют обратно клиенту. В Вашем случае клиентом выступает браузер. Он может общаться с каким-либо вебсервером (в большинстве случаем эту роль выполняет apache в связке с php) по одному из протоколов (языков обмена по сети). Как правило, это HTTP. Т.е. Вы отправляете из браузера HTTP-запрос, вебсервер его обрабатывает и отправляет обратно. Но можно обращаться и по другому протоколу (языку обмена) - websocket. Это отдельный протокол обмена, не имеющий ничего общего с HTTP. Опять же, клиентом в Вашем случае выступает браузер. Но вот незадача... нужен еще и сервер, который примет запрос, обработает его и вернет обратно по тому же протоколу. А обычный вебсервер не понимает этого "языка". Обычный вебсервер понимает только HTTP. Поэтому необходимо установить и запустить любой другой сервер (не обязательно должен быть phpDeamon), который будет принимать и обрабатывать запросы именно по протоколу websocket.

Что касается хостинга, то хостинг хостингу рознь. Но если Вы возьмете VPS да еще и с Win, то, по сути, получите в свои руки компьютер, на котором можете делать все, что душе угодно (можете при желании даже и denwer и openserver поставить). Ну а как пользоваться компьютером, думается, объяснять не нужно.

Comment: правильно ли я понял, что библиотеки с ответа выше (Ratchet, phpDaemon, Workerman) и сам скрипт демон ставится на VPS и это в связке держит соединение с клиентом и позволяет прослушивать на определенном порте связь с клиентом?

Comment: @Jarry Roxwell Под понятием "сервер" обычно подразумевают одно из двух: железо, на котором установлен серверный софт и собственно сам софт. VPS - это будет сервер ака железо (это не совсем так, но так проще). А вот программа(ы), устанавливаемая на это железо и будет Вашим сервером, о котором я вел речь. Демоны - это не есть сервер(а) - это программы, работающие в фоновом режиме в линукс-подобных системах (как службы в вин). И это не обязательно скрипт. Повторюсь, сервер - это программа, которая принимает от клиентов запросы, обрабатывает их и отправляет обратно.

Comment: @Jarry Roxwell Вот такую программу и нужно установить на VPS. Желательно, чтобы она запускалась после того как загрузилась операционная система и прошла инициализация сети. И да, она (серверная программа) работает непрерывно, при этому слушает определенный порт  - тот, который Вы укажите. На этот порт и будут стучаться клиенты. Конечно же, порт не должен использоваться другими программами на данном компьютере. Иначе сервер просто не запустится. Сервер не должен выбирать случайным образом порт. Потому как иначе клиент не будет знать куда стучаться.

Comment: @Jarry Roxwell Объясню еще на примере денвера. Денвер - это не программа - это батник (набор команд), который распаковывает и устанавливает на локальную машину три основные вещи: 1) непосредственно программу вебсервера apache; 2) библиотеки языка программирования php (с интерпретатором); 3) базу данных mysql. Из всего этого для приема и отправки запросов клиенту нужен только вебсервер apache. По умолчанию он слушает 80-й порт. Для обработки запросов apache может использовать любой из распространенных языков программирования. Но, обычно, используется php.

Answer (score 6):

Ratchet, phpDaemon, Workerman и т.д. - это библиотеки, которые помогают создавать сервер (в вашем случае Websocket) в несколько десятков строк, просто реализовав предоставленный интерфейс библиотекой (onClose, onOpen, onMessage, onError) и работая с функциями, которые написаны уже до вас.

После чего вы запускаете PHP-скрипт, который является демоном, и он прослушивает порт для соединения и выдает ответы клиентам по реализованному интерфейсу.

Нет, конечно вы можете это написать сами и использовать вместо нескольких строчек собственную библиотеку, но у вас уйдет много времени, ведь вам нужно разбираться в тонкостях протокола, в процессе handshake, передаче заголовков, отправке сообщений, написать различные функции, обработку клиентов, потратить время на отладку... А тут все написано до вас.

Что подразумевается под реальным хостингом? Если shared, то вряд-ли (из-за ограничений, но лучше уточнить у хостера, на VPS точно получится).

Пример реализации сервера на Rachet, есть на [github библиотеки Rachet](https://github.com/ratchetphp/Ratchet)

Comment: Хостинг sprinthost, но подозреваю не про это вопрос. А в чем заключается особенность демона? Он запускается по расписанию, или всегда работает, если второе то его запуск производится вручную? и может ли он сам завершится через какое-то время?

Comment: Демон работает всегда, на то он и демон, чтобы всегда быть готовым к новым соединениям. Вы самостоятельно его должны закрывать и открывать. Если есть желание, можете написать функцию, которая будет закрывать процесс через какое-то время, но я не видел проектов, кто этим промышляет :)

Comment: А возможна такая ситуация что демон прекратит работу сам? И когда выбираю порт для прослушки, выбирается рандомный, лишь бы он не был занят или тоже какие-то тонкости есть? Глянул про VPS, но не совсем понял для чего нужен еще один хоть и виртуальный сервер, для решения этой задачи.

Comment: Вы самостоятельно выбираете порт, демон завершит работу, если произойдет Fatal error. Чтобы прослушивать порт на сервере, нужны права на это, обычный виртуальный хостинг может запретить подобные действия и скорее всего запретит.

Comment: Можете подсказать как сделать чат с комнатами? Уже неделю а то и больше пытаюсь найти информацию

Answer (score 0):

Коллеги, разрешите посоветовать вам более удобный инструмент - [wsphp.net](http://wsphp.net)
Используя его, не нужно что-то кардинально менять подходях к программированию на PHP.
Как обычно используем $_GET, $_SESSION и прочие переменные. То, что надо вернуть клиенту, возвращаем в stdout. В общем, никаких отличий с точки зрения PHP - работаем по websocket или HTTP...

Comment: он не полностью бесплатен, Сколько стоит? И как подружиь его с apache, fastcgi?