# Чат на сокетах в связке с PHP?

Tags: php, websocket

Стоит задача "простенький чат, возможно, с "будущим" (апдейты в качестве функционала) на PHP".

Выбор у меня особо не велик(так как проект написан на php (laravel, про pusher знаю)), то больше нужно смотреть на ratchet (если я все правильно понял).
Пробовал socket.io и ratchet - если честно, не совсем понял самой сути.
Так вот, вопрос в следующем: (сейчас чат на главной странице) имеет ли смысл вынести чат на отдельную страницу и сделать его на node ? (или какие вообще имеются варианты?)

P.s: чат сугубо для общения пользователей, т.е - сильных наворотов (типа комнат) мне не нужно, но тем не менее, нужен лайв чат(и так понятно).
Ранее дел с подобной темой не имел, поэтому не знаю.

Подскажите, как лучше поступить будет?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Я отвечал на подобный вопрос здесь: [WebSocket с серверной частью на php](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/551293/websocket-%d1%81-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%8e-%d0%bd%d0%b0-php/551309#551309)

Вам нужно создать чат, значит нужно использовать веб-сокеты, для этого есть библиотеки, они позволяют его написать в несколько десятков строк, достаточно просто реализовать интерфейсы. По ссылке выше есть полное описание, почему и какие библиотеки лучше использовать. Можете писать серверную часть на чем хотите, хоть на PHP, хоть на NodeJs, разницы особой не будет.

Смысл веб-сокетов, что у вас поверх HTTP интерфейса открывается сокет, через который серверное приложение может отправлять Вам сообщения, а вы ему можете отправлять сообщения, такой двунаправленный протокол.

Answer (score 0):

Зачем придумывать велосипеды ?
Вот готовый сокет с примерами https://github.com/morozovsk/websocket!

Еще и статьи есть на хабре) с подробными объяснениями, разбитый на 3 части по сложности:

https://habrahabr.ru/post/209864/

Плюсы в том, что есть готовые примеры с работающими чатами и даже небольшой игрой!