# Реализация чата на сайте

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Пишу для сайта чат не большой и с толкнулся с проблемой как правильно построить опрос на предмет новых сообщений.
Проблемы заключаются вот в чем:

1. Если опрос делать бесконесным циклом while(true) и использовать sleep(1) то если каждый раз когда обновляешь страницу происходит долгая обработка данных. Конечно session_write_close() не много помогает **НО** не для всех ПК... то есть если ПК слабый то результат ровным счетом не меняется мы остаемся так же с долгой загрузкой.
2. Опрос делать к примеру раз в секунду к БД с помощью ajax и тут я так понимаю будет нагрузка идти на БД от частых запросов.

И сам вопрос как правильно реализовать опрос на предмет новых сообщений что бы это не нагружало системы как у клиента так же и самого сервака?

UPD:

Скажите пожалуйста на сколько хороша такая реализация?

на странице index.html/php делаем ajax запрос на страницу ... ну пускай будет эта страница просто page.php

**index.html/php**

```
<script>
    // (B) LAST UPDATED TIMESTAMP
    var last = 0;

    // (C) AJAX LONG POLL
    function poll () {
      // (C1) FORM DATA
      let data = new FormData();
      data.append("last", last);

      // (C2) FETCH
      console.log("Fetch run");
      fetch("page.php", { method:"POST", body:data })
      .then((res) => { return res.json(); })

      // (C3) UPDATE ON SERVER RESPONSE
      .then((data) => {
        // HTML DISPLAY
        let sb = document.getElementById("scoreboard");
        sb.innerHTML = `[${data.time}] ${data.home} - ${data.away}`;

        // NEXT ROUND
        last = data.unix;
        poll();
      })

      // (C4) CATCH ERROR - LOOP ON TIMEOUT
      .catch((err) => { poll(); });
    }

    // (D) GO!
    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", poll);
</script>
```

**page.php**

```
<?php
// (A) TIME LIMIT & ABORT
set_time_limit(30); // SET THE APPROPRIATE TIME LIMIT
ignore_user_abort(false); // STOP WHEN LONG POLLING BREAKS

// (B) DATABASE SETTINGS - CHANGE THESE TO YOUR OWN!
define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
define("DB_NAME", "test");
define("DB_CHAR", "utf8");
define("DB_USER", "root");
define("DB_PASS", "");

// (C) DATABASE CLASS
class DB {
  // (C1) CONSTRUCTOR - CONNECT TO DATABASE
  protected $pdo = null;
  protected $stmt = null;
  function __construct () {
    try {
      $this->pdo = new PDO(
        "mysql:host=".DB_HOST.";charset=".DB_CHAR.";dbname=".DB_NAME,
        DB_USER, DB_PASS
      );
    } catch (Exception $ex) { exit($ex->getMessage()); }
  }

  // (C2) DESTRUCTOR - CLOSE CONNECTION
  function __destruct () {
    if ($this->stmt !== null) { $this->stmt = null; }
    if ($this->pdo !== null) { $this->pdo = null; }
  }

  // (C3) GET LATEST SCORE
  function getScore () {
    $this->stmt = $this->pdo->prepare(
      "SELECT *, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`time`) AS `unix`
       FROM `score` ORDER BY `time` DESC LIMIT 1"
    );
    $this->stmt->execute();
    return $this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  }
}
$DB = new DB();

// (D) LOOP - CHECK FOR SCORE UPDATES
// WILL KEEP LOOPING UNTIL A SCORE UPDATE OR TIMEOUT
if (isset($_POST["last"])) { while (true) {
  $score = $DB->getScore();
  if (isset($score["unix"]) && $score["unix"] > $_POST["last"]) {
    echo json_encode($score);
    break;
  }
  sleep(1); // NOT TO BREAK THE SERVER. SHORT PAUSE BEFORE NEXT CHECK.
}}
```

Этот пример я нашел на одном из сайтов вот только бы понять на сколько хорош это вариант

---

Подскажите пожалуйста по следующему моменту:
Я знаю что на C# есть такая тема что если объявить какую то переменную ну для примера пускай будет $show = false; (И тут сразу скажу что точно сейчас не помню как правильно на C# задаются переменные это чисто для примера) и при нажатии кнопки одного из пользователя задать этой переменной значение true то у всех пользователей значение переменной $show станет true.  Возможно ли такое сделать и на PHP?

Comment: Не знаю как обновления происходят при правке НО все же хотелось бы узнать на сколько хороший вариант который я нашёл

Answer (score 0):

Тут лучше использовать websocket и на сервере при создании нового сообщения, оповещать пользователей через сокет об этом. Но на php реализовать это не самая лучшая идея, лучше использовать nodejs на сервере вместе с ним. Или можешь использовать long-poling, facebook раньше его использовал, но то-же достаточно муторная вещь в реализации. Опросы раз в какое-то время очень очень плохая идея, т.к. при 1000+ пользователях сервер ляжет.

Вот более подробный ответ о реализации сокетов на php (без nodejs): [WebSocket с серверной частью на php](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/551293/websocket-%d1%81-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%8e-%d0%bd%d0%b0-php/551309#551309)

Готовый пример long-poling на php: https://github.com/panique/php-long-polling

Comment: Websocket это конечно хорошо но к сожалению хостер не дает возможности с ним поработать. Меня хостера не хотят и по этому ищу другие пути решения данной задачи.

Comment: Ну так можно сокеты и на php реализовать. На крайний случай long-poling, хотя можно упереться в максимальное время выполнение скрипта, если вы на обычном хостинге.

Comment: Если вы будите посылать запросы на сервер даже раз в 10 секунд, этого будет достаточно чтобы положить сервер на обычном облачном хостинге при 100+ пользователях

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. Как раз изучаю long-poling и тот пример (первый) который я сейчас нашел как раз построен на бесконечном цикле while(true) теперь осталось понять как его реализовать что бы не нагружал систему.

Answer (score 0):

Если хостел не дает использовать websocket можете использовать pusher
https://pusher.com/
с малым данным бесплатно
просто отправлять будете event и слушать его как socket если будет трудности могу сказать что и как